# Insert FAT after loader

Tags: assembly, filesystems, boot

I'm trying to make bootloader which will load second stage to memory. After I'll be done I want to load file from FAT12 filesystem. My problem is that I don't know how can I add FATs (2 for FAT12) after sectors reserved for boot and second stage. I cannot use formatting tool because it starts on floppy start and there's bootloader. Does anybody know how it is possible? I'm reading [this](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/) tutorial but there is not written how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FAT12 file system reserves the first 512 bytes for the boot sector. A good formatting tool will let you load a custom boot sector onto the disk.

I use [UltraISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/) for creating disk images. It lets you:

- Add or extract files to and from a disk image with one click.
- Create audio CD's, data CD/DVD's, bootable CD/DVD's, and floppy and HDD images.
- Use predefined boot sectors from disks such as MS-DOS and Windows.
- Burn and rip image files to and from physical disks.
- And more.

To create an bootable floppy with UltraISO, just create an empty floppy image, and load a boot sector onto it. You can then add or remove files, or load a new boot sector without trouble.

Comment: Two questions: 

Can I use partcopy to load bootloader? Or how can I do it?

If I have two reserved sectors (bootloader and second stage for loading kernel), how can I use it?

Comment: Do you have the second stage as a file? If you don't store it as a file, then you will have to do some hacking to get a file system that works. You can also store it as a file with a known address, and load it directly, though that will require you to hardcode the file size. I've never used PartCopy, but it looks perfect for your situation.